# Can Dependency Injection be considered to be a replacement for factory method pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

According to wikipedia

> In class-based programming, the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created.

In dependency injection also(I have experience of spring so this may be in that context), we have Variables for each class defined using interfaces, and leave the concrete instantiation to the DI framework.

Am I missing something in this or can these be used interchangeably?

Comment: The application context in Spring is a bean factory, so my answer is "yes".  Perhaps the subtlety comes in when you realize that DI requires a bean factory, but there's much more (e.g. pre- and post-bean processors, etc.)

Comment: @duffymo Yes Spring is much more than that, but I was just thinking about it in light of IoC and DI not specifically in terms of a framework.

Comment: **Primarily Opinion Based** - *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: consider your question in the context that a constructor is the *original dependency injection* and also known as *the poor mans dependency injection framework* also consider that every DI framework has the concept of *Providers* that are *factories for dependencies* that you use to *Inject* for late late bound dependencies, it becomes obvious it is not as clear cut as you make it out to be.

Comment: Factory method pattern is about subclasses being able to override some “create” method that instantiates an object. Dependency injection is about replacing a direct instantiation of a property by “injection” (through a constructor in the simplest case). Those look like completely different ideas to me.

Comment: I would say the answer to your question is: yes, use of DI and (SOLID design in general) can reduce the need of the Factory Pattern. Mark Seemann and I describe this in chapter 6.2 of [Dependency Injection in .NET, second edition](https://www.manning.com/seemann2/) in detail, and I [blogged](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) about this in the past, and a very small excerpt of 6.2 can be found online [here](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-abuse-of-abstract-factories/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Dependency Injection be considered to be a replacement for factory
>   method pattern?

Yes but Dependency Injection goes even beyond.
So, you should consider it rather as an improvement in terms of design.

It is right that the two ways provide very close facilities.
But note also that the Dependency injection principle has something that differs really from a raw factory pattern : the dependency inversion principle.
I like very much the Hollywood metaphor to illustrate that : “don't call us, we'll call you".
It is essential as it relieves the client classes to lookup its dependencies : the framework does/("call" to take back the metaphor) it for you.
As a consequence, clients don't have any longer a coupling with factory structures (and the boiler plate code associated to) and just need to define their dependencies and these will be injected.

Comment: Dependency Injection and Factory Method are distinct patterns. They can be used together. They can be used separately. One is not a replacement for the other. Erich Gamma has [noted](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1404056) that in a "refactored" design patterns book, the GoF would add Dependency Injection as a creational pattern alongside Factory.

Comment: @jaco0646 I didn't tell that it was the same pattern and that they cannot be used together.